# Adobe Air Invisible Buttons on Android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-builder

I am creating my first Adobe Air application from a Flash animation file via Flash Builder (I am an Android developer by trade.)  One of the last updates I had to make was updating some of the text fields within the app to be dynamic so their text can be set at runtime via ActionScript.

When I view the app via the Adobe Air Simulator or push to an iOS device the buttons work fine, but when I push to an Android device some Buttons and Movie Clips are invisible.  I can still click on the buttons if I touch where they should be on the screen but I cannot see them.  In my testing of a fix I set the alpha of a button which is affected by this issue to 100 but it still shows as invisible.

Is this a known issue?  How would I go about ensuring that all Buttons and Movie Clips are visible to the user?

Thanks,
Adam

Edit:
The only change to my code in order to set the text is running the following AS:
`play_play.text = TranslationUtils.getTranslationText(TranslationUtils.PLAY_PLAY);`

The AS for the TranslationUtils class is an external AS file which `switch`s through constants to return the correct text, based on the device's `Capabilities.language`

Comment: there's no display issues in AIR, if it doesn't show it's because your code and your code only doesn't allow it. Your code might send those button to a lower indexed display list so they don't show, it might make them invisible, it might set them outside the screen boundaries or whatever else it's doing but that's all in your code. If you can still click them chances are they are invisible (alpha = 0). btw alpha values are between 0 to 1, setting to anything above 1 has no effect.

Comment: Are you using GPU render mode? If so, do they show up if you use CPU render mode?

Comment: Do you use custom skins for the buttons ? Android is using a different Button skin than iOS if i remember correctly

Comment: Originally it was rendered in GPU mode.  If I switch to CPU mode I can see my screen elements correctly, but the animations are super slow, like 1/4 the normal speed.  Is there an easy fix to speed that up? (I know that's probably a loaded question)

Comment: I don't think the buttons have custom skins.  They're custom buttons, so we made them with our own shapes in the different states.  There are also MovieClips which are not showing up, I'm not sure if that helps at all.

Comment: Are you applying Filters to the buttons? They wont show correctly in GPU mode if you use Filters and try to test it on device. However by converting it to a Bitmap or PNG then you will be able to use filters on buttons and render in GPU mode for performance increase

Comment: I am not.  All of the buttons and MovieClips were showing up correctly before the addition of the code which gets the localized text and sets it to the dynamic labels.